# PHP-GDS Sort queries from AppEngine DataStore

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've created an index using a schema using the awesome [PHP-GDS](https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds):

```
$obj_product_schema = (new Schema('Product'))
   ->addString('url')
   ->addString('date')
   ->addString('name', TRUE)
   ->addInteger('votes', TRUE);
```

However if I try to return a subset of objects with a sorted query as follows I get a 'no matching index found' error.

```
$queryStr = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE date='" . $dateQ . '" ORDER BY votes ASC ";
$obj_event_store->query($queryStr); 
$products = $obj_event_store->fetchPage(5);
```

The error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/app/runQuery: (412) no matching index found.'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424157/how-to-build-datastore-indexes-php-gae/28480515#28480515     You have the same problem ;) just run in devserver first, then upload :). What you show is not an index, but your schema.

Comment: Sorry Patrice but please read the question. The queries work fine when retrieving data e.g '"SELECT * FROM Product WHERE date='" . $dateQ . '" works but when the 'ORDER BY' is appended the query fails with the 'no matching index found' error.

Comment: Your order by also has an influence on the needed index, so it's very possible you have an index for date, but not one for "date+vote". I'll stand by my point as a first thing to try before investigating further ;). Post your datastore-index.yaml in here as well maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put "true" on your parameter, it did create an index for that single parameter. I think the confusion was between single parameter indexes and composite indexes(I just saw your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658555/appengine-datastore-gql-not-returning-any-results) answered by Tom).

While these single parameter indexes indeed works for single parameter queries (`SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y = whatever`, where it only needs an index for Y), when you add an order by on a different parameter, it needs a composite index (`SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y = whatever ORDER BY Z`, where it needs Y and Z). You can't declare them in your schema directly, they need to be uploaded with your application (in a file called `index.yaml`).

Think of it this way : your datastore currently has an index where the **only** info available to it is the date, and the key of the object. It also has another index where the **only** info available is the vote and the key of the object. How would it know what to return if you ask for a date with a vote order by? That's why you need to add an index where the info available is the date **and** the vote, with the key of the object, so your datastore can lookup into that table

As a side note : the system has gotten better than it was before : it can now use the ZigZag merge algorithm to make more complex indexes out of simpler ones (there are still limitations around this though, and obviously, performance is impacted).

*More information in a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424157/how-to-build-datastore-indexes-php-gae/28480515#28480515)*